# Sonarpython not scanning Jupyter notebook .ipynb

Tags: python, sonarqube, jupyter-notebook, sonarqube-scan

I am using Sonarqube to scan my GIT repository , and have Installed a plugin called "SonarPython".

It scans all python files (.py) but does not pick up any of the jupyter notebook with extension (.ipynb).

Is this a right plugin to scan jupyter notebook ? Are there any other ways scan jupyter notebook in SonarPython

My Sonar project file

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=Python:KeyValueeeeeee
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=Myproject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# This property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
sonar.sources=./

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Even added a setting on Sonarqube :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add ipynb in next line as shown in image below.

[image]

Comment: This actually doesn't really helps as the notebook files will be analyzed as python files and   there will be a lot of noise in the analysis